# Getting the Eclipse application launcher name

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

Does someone know how to get the LauncherName of an Eclipse application inside the code? Usually this is configured in the .product file, but I need to get this value in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path of the launcher is returned by:

```
System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher");
```

and the name by:

```
System.getProperty("eclipse.launcher.name");
```